# Replace part of a string from a certain point

Tags: php, regex, string

The string

`abc/def/*`

or

`abc/def/*/xyz`

How can I use preg_replace_callback to replace everything after `/*` with a certain string?

Like

`abc/def/replacement`

Comment: I don't know, but i guess you don't want to manualy chech for present of "/*", then cut the string to the position of "/*" and then add the replacement?

Comment: So in both examples, the result will be the same (the value you have under "Like") ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$string = "abc/dc/*bla/foo";

$string = preg_replace_callback(
    '~/\*.*~',
    create_function(
      '$match',
      'return "/replacement";'
    ),
    $string
);

var_dump($string);
?>
```

output

```
string 'abc/dc/replacement' (length=19)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
$text = "abc/def/*/xyz";
function rep($matches)
{
  return "/replacement";
}
echo preg_replace_callback("|/\*.*|", "rep", $text);
```

Do you really need to use preg_replace_callback though?  Here is an equivalent version with preg_replace:

```
$text = "abc/def/*/xyz";
echo preg_replace("|/\*.*|", "/replacement", $text);
```